# IE11/Edge doesn't respect link/css order in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, dom

tl;dr: IE11/Edge seems to give priority to styles in CSS files loaded last with javascript rather than how they appear in the DOM structure.

I cannot find anyone else who has reported this problem, but am looking for help confirming my issue.

I have a function for loading JS libraries (locally if the cdn fails) and this includes a line to either 'appendTo' or 'prependTo' the 'head' element (passes in 'method').

```
$("<link>", { rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css", "href": css })[method]("head");
```

The issue is that core website style may override library styles, so I thought 'prependTo' the 'head' would work to ensure the core styles override the library - this does work in Firefox & Chrome. But in IE the library styles are still overriding as though the CSS file was after the core files in the DOM even through inspecting the DOM shows that it is before.

In my case, I am loading dataTables CSS & JS from local versions if the CDN fails - and since I want my custom website CSS to override the library, I am using 'prependTo' to make sure the dataTables CSS is before my custom website CSS in the document head tag. IE11 still applies it 'last' or gives it preference. It's true when emulating IE10 etc. though I no longer have a test area for 'real' old IE versions to verify if this was always true.

Can you confirm this is the functionality in IE? Do you know when this started? Do you know a fix? Trying to avoid a bunch of "!important" in my CSS files.

Comment: I've posted about something similar before, though I can't find the details now. The CSS 2 spec was rather vague about this. It just said "sort by order specified:  ..., the latter specified wins." but didn't clarify what "the order specified" meant in cases like this. The [CSS 3 cascading draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-3/#cascade-order) makes clear that the order to be used is "document order" - i.e. what Chrome and Firefox do, but it is still a draft.

Comment: If it works in other browsers but not IE, then the style rules are missing the ms prefixed or the standard rule names. You should be able to use the DOM Explorer tab of any browser to the applied rules and how they cascade to the selected element. see caniuse.com for css rule support in browsers... IE and edge do not recognise the appearance rules. (-webkit-appearance, -moz-appearance, -k-appearance.) Please provide a reproduction url with your questions.

Comment: @RobParsons sorry, that has nothing to do with it. When the css file is in the HTML before my core CSS on page load it works fine, but when I have to add it after page load with javascript it is treated as the last to apply/given preference even if I insert the CSS file in the DOM before my core CSS - IE treats last loaded as preference instead of order in the DOM like FF & Chrome do / what I'd expect.

Comment: Does the DOM explorer tool in IE show that any rules from the injected stylesheet have been applied? Try injecting before the window.onload event is called, in a script block at the bottom of the body block.

Comment: @RobParsons If you read my question it will explain everything you need to know. IE is giving priority to a CSS file loaded via javascript even though I load it before other CSS files in the DOM. So priority to last loaded instead of order in the DOM unlike other browsers.

Comment: terraEllise - please post a reproduction url.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the exact same problem even on Edge 16. My unfortunate work around is to manually attach any  css via JavaScript instead of in my html/page template.

```js
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = '/link/to/style.css';
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(link);
```